# VS Code - Keyboard shortcut to open Git hunk change preview?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Currently if I want to open the Git hunk change preview, I need to move my mouse and click on the gutter to open the preview window:

[image: opening hunk preview]

How can I add a keyboard shortcut such that it opens the preview window if I use it while my cursor is within the hunk?

```json
{
  "key": "F12",
  "command": /* ??? */,
  "when": /* ??? */
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>

It is the keyboard shortcut for "Show Next Change", and it opens the diff hunk.
But you still have to click in the diff view in order to shift focus from the editor.